# Socket server problem: socket server crashing

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, socketexception

We have a .Net application running as a service listening on a TCP port for traffic using TCPClient. It can run successfully for days and thousands of connections, but at some point,
the service crashes with this exception in Windows Event Viewer:

Signature of the problem :

```
Application: WindowsService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at WindowsService.Connexion.AcceptCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: https://docs.tibbo.com/taiko/sock_tcp_reconnects This may help to understand it. 
Try to handle the exception and use Socket.EndReceive when this happens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.endreceive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_EndReceive_System_IAsyncResult_

Comment: Hi, @simali. Could you add your code where you handle the new connection and receive data?

Comment: Hi, @simali, I modified my answer, but it's not finally so I need you to share the ErrorCode, it's really important, check my upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Simali, welcome to Stackoverflow.

First of all, when you post a question, is a requirement to post the code into your question rather than in comments. StackOverflows allows you to edit your question. In this time, I add your code in my answer:

```cs
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
    Socket socket; 
    try { 
        socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR); 
        Log.CreatLog("Client connected, server waiting for request ... "); 
        
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallbackAsync, socket); 
        
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null); 
    }catch (ObjectDisposedException e) { 
        Log.CreatLog("ObjectDisposedException !!!"); return; 
    } 
}
```

Now, as your stack error shows, the error is located at `socket.BeginReceive` and the exception thrown is `SocketException`, which is one of the four different exceptions that `BeginReceive`can throw:

- **ArgumentNullException**
- **SocketException**, which means: An error occurred when attempting to access the socket.
- **ObjectDisposedException**
- **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

This information can be checked in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive?view=net-5.0).

Your program is crashing because you are handling `ObjectDisposedException` but not the others, like `SocketException` in this case. So you should add the `SocketException` and print the Message and stack error that the program is getting at the moment of the exception; something like this:

```cs
private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {
    Socket socket; 
    try { 
        socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR); 
        Log.CreatLog("Client connected, server waiting for request ... "); 
        
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallbackAsync, socket); 
        
        serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null); 
    }catch (ObjectDisposedException e) { 
        Log.CreatLog("ObjectDisposedException !!!" + e); return; 
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) { 
        Log.CreatLog("SocketException !!!: " + e); return; 
    } 
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e) { 
        Log.CreatLog("ArgumentOutOfRangeException !!!" + e); return; 
    } 
    catch (ArgumentNullException e) { 
        Log.CreatLog("ArgumentNullException !!!" + e); return; 
    } 
}
```

> I added the other exceptions because I don't know if your program has other issues with socket reception.

In this way you'll have more information about the error and your program will have more chances to get by the exception.

**Important**: In the same way that this exception rose at `socket.BeginReceive`, you could have more exceptions in this function, like [BeginAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginaccept?view=net-5.0). So I recommend you to check all the possible exceptions that async socket throws and handled them.

### **

### UPGRADE (Jul 5th):

**

Simail: To add more information on my answer, your output is not enough to give you a correct answer. `SocketException` can have several reasons, so you need to print the ErrorCode, as windows documentation says:

> If you receive a SocketException, use the [SocketException.ErrorCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception.errorcode?view=net-5.0) property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the [Windows Sockets version 2 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) error code documentation for a detailed description of the error.

Most of the time the problem is raised by code, but, in some cases, is an exception triggered by the network but, with the information that you shared, it's not possible to know what the problem is between clients and your server.

After you shared the ErrorCode, i may help you to identify the cause of the problem.

Let me know it, when you would've caught the error code.